# Изменение геттера свойства через рефлексию

Tags: c#

Класс со свойством:

```
using System;

namespace CSrharpApplicationTest
{
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public int MyProperty { get; } = 1;

        public void Method()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(MyProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

Основная программа:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace CSrharpApplicationTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SomeClass x = new SomeClass();
            x.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(x.MyProperty))/*Дальше что писать - не понял.*/;
        }
    }
}
```

Цель такая: средствами рефлексии поменять геттер `MyProperty`. Проблема в том, что в основном я могу только читать информацию о свойстве, а не изменять её.

Comment: Это возможно, но сложно в реализации - [1](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463508/NET-CLR-Injection-Modify-IL-Code-during-Run-time), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299097/dynamically-replace-the-contents-of-a-c-sharp-method), [3](https://github.com/pardeike/Harmony).

Comment: Зачем вообще такое понадобилось? Добавьте сеттер, если вам надо писать в свойство...

Comment: Это - вопрос об изменении кодом самого же себя. А так - да (если не стоит задача изменения кодом самого себя), согласен, что в данном случае Ваш вариант - более оптимален и адекватен.